# Subgroups of the symmetry group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Question:

Let $A = \{\{x,y\}:x,y\in\{1,2,...,n\},x\neq y\}$. We want to show that $\exists G\leq \text{Sym(A)}$ s.t. $G\cong S_n$ and $\{g(\{1,2\}):g\in G\}=A$

Attempt:

For the first part I'm pretty sure I have to use the first isomorphism theorem which will give that for a homomorphism $f:C\rightarrow D$, $C/\text{Ker}f\cong \text{Im}f\leq D$. In this case I think that D will be Sym(S) however I'm completely lost as to what the group C would be and what exactly the homomorphism would be. From there I'm assuming the image will likely be something that is clearly isomorphic to $S_n$. For the second part I'm thinking that the homomorphism should make it clear what the Coset is.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n$ act on $A$ in the following way:

$\sigma\cdot\{x,y\}=\{\sigma(x),\sigma(y)\}$.

This group action is *transitive* and *faithful*.

Do you know how group actions on $X$ relate to $\text{Sym}(X)$?

Comment: No I'm not sure how group actions on X relate to Sym(X). From what I've gathered from reading up on a group action being transitive and faithful, $S_n$ acts faithfully on A $\iff$ the homomorphism $f:S_n\rightarrow \text{Sym(A)}$ has a trivial kernel and as it's clearly going to be injective it will and $S_n$ acts transitively on A $\iff$ $\forall\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\in A$ $\exists\sigma\in S_n$ s.t. $\sigma(\{a,b\})=\{c,d\}$. Not sure if I'm right on the definitions and I'm unsure how this helps the proof?

Comment: @John You're almost there. Take $G$ to be the image of the homomorphism $f:S_n\to\text{Sym}(A)$. Since $f$ is injective, $G$ is isomorphic to $S_n$. Since the action is transitive, $\{g(\{1,2\}):g\in G\}=A$.